# Is the "data" chunk always the last chunk in a WAV file?

Tags: audio, format, wav, specifications

I'm trying to write software that reads a WAV file and I want to validate whether the size provided in the "RIFF" header actually matches the size of the file. Currently my software will loop through each chunk and stop once it reads the "data" chunk.

In every file I have encountered, the "data" chunk is the last chunk in the file, but I haven't found any specification that explicitly states it MUST be the last chunk in the file.

Is it technically valid for a WAV file to have additional chunks after the "data" chunk? Or can I safely assume that any file that does this is not conforming to the standard format?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* technically valid for a WAV file to have additional chunks after the `data` chunk. And you will find WAV files like this out in the wild.

The only chunk ordering requirement within the "WAVE" form is that the `fmt` chunk must occur before the `data` chunk. From p56 of the [1.0 Microsoft/IBM spec](https://www.aelius.com/njh/wavemetatools/doc/riffmci.pdf):

> The WAVE form is defined as follows. Programs must expect (and ignore)
> any unknown chunks encountered, as with all RIFF forms. However,
> `fmt-ck` must always occur before `wave-data`, and both of these
> chunks are mandatory in a WAVE file.

Note also the "expect (and ignore) any unknown chunks" requirement. If you're writing code to read in WAV files that are generated by all kinds of other software, (e.g. Audacity, Reaper, ProTools, etc.) then you don't want to fail reading the WAV when it has some extra chunks like `list` and `cue`.

For compatibility, the best way to write your WAV decoder is to read chunk headers after the RIFF/WAVE header and use that header info to either skip over a chunk or process it:

```
   read RIFF/WAVE header
   while read position is not at EOF
     read next 4 bytes (chunk ID)
     read next 4 bytes (chunk data size)
     if chunk ID matches 'fmt ', 'data' or an ID your app cares about...
       read the chunk data and parse what you need
     else
       advance read position by chunk data size
```

If you are *encoding* a WAVE file, it's an unfortunate *defacto* standard to first write `header` + `fmt` + `data` and then follow the `data` chunk with any extra chunks beyond that. This is to accommodate all the people in the World that wrote off-spec readers by assuming all WAV files would only ever follow the `header` + `fmt` + `data` chunk sequence. (angry nerd fist shaking)

Answer (score 0):

RIFF files may contain several types of information. WAV format is a private case of RIFF. According to this [link](http://www.tactilemedia.com/info/MCI_Control_Info.html) there may be some other chunks in a WAV file, like FACT chunk and Cue-Points chunk, altough - " must always occur before , and both of these chunks are mandatory in a WAVE file."

Comment: Hmm... That explicitly states that the "fmt" chunk must occur before the "data" chunk, but it does not explicitly state that the other chunks cannot come afterward. I've never seen a wavefile with additional chunks after the data chunk, but unless its explicitly required that the data chunk is last I think it might be safer if my code does not make that assumption.